# How to work on react native for windows using VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, react-native-windows

I'm always working in VS Code and decided to try out React Native for Windows. I followed instructions [here](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/getting-started). But after I ran command `npx react-native run-windows` I got following error:

```
error Unable to find vswhere
```

I searched online and so far found that React Native for Windows should be developed using Visual Studio. Is there a way to develop using VS Code without downloading full Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

please kindly post on https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows instead.
This should be possible if you install the rnw dependencies.